# Virtualkeyboard using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the colors of my keybuttons from my javascript code my keys are displayed within "td class" how can I change the color of my keybuttons using javascript code.

Comment: What is _color of keybutton_? Background color, text color? When you want ot change color: when button pressed, on initial creation? Some simple example is desired.

Comment: It is Backgroundcolor and it should change color on creation  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SCRIPT:

```
var tdKeyButton=document.getElementById('#idOfSomeButton'); // or any other code for getting pointer to `TD` element of virtual key button.
tdKeyButton.className="SomeKeyButtonCssClassName";
// or for multiple CSS classes
// tdKeyButton.className+=" SomeKeyButtonCssClassName";
// or with inline style
// tdKeyButton.style.backgroundColor="#F0000F";
```

CSS style:

```
   .SomeKeyButtonCssClassName {
      background-color: #F0000F;
   }
```

See: CSS `background-color` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-color

Comment: can i give color in javascript code like style.backgroundColor rather than creating a css.

Comment: i want to give the color to the button using javascript rather than in css my keybuttons are tagged within td class

Comment: @Ashish: yes you can give color in javascript code like style.backgroundColor: see my answer in commented lines: `tdKeyButton.style.backgroundColor="#F0000F";` or you can set color with rgba() as `tdKeyButton.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.5);"`